# How can I exploit store by value to clone an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am storing css values in an object for use in two different scenarios:

```
styles = {
  on: { left:10, top:20 },
  off: { left:0, top:30 }
};
```

The first way I use this is for a simple mouseover effect:

```
$nav.hover(
  function() {
    $(this).css(styles.on);
  },
  function() {
    $(this).css(styles.off);
  }
);
```

However, for my other use I am doing an animation and I need extra (non-css) properties like `ease` and `onComplete`. Ideally I would like to be able to duplicate the `styles` object and append my new properties to it like this:

```
var anim = styles;
anim.ease = Power3.easeInOut;
anim.onComplete = function() {/*stuff*/};
```

This will work fine for the second use but unfortunately due to storing a reference-by-value this also adds the new properties to the original `styles` variable as well, which in turn will cause the `.css()` method to try and assign `ease` etc as a css value.

How can I quickly clone the source object to add in the new properties without affecting the original?

I am aware of the arguments surrounding whether Javascript can pass by reference ([Is there thing like pass by value pass by reference in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835070/is-there-thing-like-pass-by-value-pass-by-reference-in-javascript), [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)) but I don't want to get into a discussion on that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it the other way round (copy from `styles` to the new object with custom properties) and use [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend):

```
$(this).animate($.extend({
   ease: Power3.easeInOut,
   onComplete: function() {/*stuff*/}
}, styles.off));
```

If you want to override some of them, you also can clone with `$.extend` by copying properties into a new object:

```
$(this).animate($.extend({}, styles.off,
   left: 5,
   ease: Power3.easeInOut,
   onComplete: function() {/*stuff*/}
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, a simple object literal, the quick and dirty way would be this:

```
var anim = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(styles));
```

If the `styles` object will always be as straightforward as this, then you should be OK. Of course, if you're going to mess around with functions (methods), or multi-level, circular references in there, you might need to put a bit more effort into things.

If the `styles` is unpredictable, but you want to be able to access it from its clone, you could do something like this:

```
var anim = {on: {}, off: {}};
for (var prop in anim)
{//only loop through anim's properties, as we don't know how many "styles" might have
    if (anim.hasOwnProperty(prop))
    {
        anim[prop].left = styles[prop].left || 'default value';
        anim[prop].top = styles[prop].top || 'default value';
    }
}
anim.original = styles;//reference original object...
```

In theory, you could create a constructor that uses the original object as a prototype, but that would be somewhat overkill IMHO