# Javascript multiple assignment clarification?

Tags: javascript

Looking at `var a=b=1;` , I already know that both `a` and `b` has the same value.

But my question is :

Does the `a` gets its value from `1` or from  `b` ?

I made a small [**test**](http://jsbin.com/UVuseqU/2/edit) :

```
/*1*/   (function (){
/*2*/     var j = window.j = function (){ alert('3');};
/*3*/     window.j2 = j;
/*4*/   })();
/*5*/   
/*6*/   window.j(); //3
/*7*/   window.j=null;
/*8*/   window.j2();//3
```

As you can see line #8 yields `3` so I persume that `a` is not having the value of `b` but the value of `1`.

Am I right ?

visualize :

```
(function (){
  var j = window.j = function (){ alert('3');};
      |
      |          ^        ^
      |          |        |            //which one ?
      +----------+--------+  
})();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758576/multiple-left-hand-assignment-with-javascript

Comment: @MarkWalters I already read it. but it doesnt state from where `a` got the value. it talks about scoping which I already know that.

Comment: You are right, as one of the answers also states in @MarkWalters link,  assignment in javascript works from right to left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assignment in javascript works from right to left. So you are getting your value from `window.j`. Re-setting `window.j` will not affect the result because Javascript variables always passes by value, exception is array or object.

Example of passing value by ref in JS object:

```
var obj = { x: 2 };
var anotherObj = obj;
anotherObj.x++;
alert(obj.x); //3
```

You can find more information [here](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass).

More useful examples available in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835070/is-there-thing-like-pass-by-value-pass-by-reference-in-javascript).

Comment: can u provide example for an array scenario ?

Comment: What about : var obj = function (){}; ?

Comment: Doesn't make any difference because every function in JavaScript is actually a Function object.

Answer (score 0):

[Assigment in JavaScript is right associative](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), so you are correct. 
In

```
a = b = c;
```

`a` takes the value of `b` at time of assignment, so if `b` is later assigned to something else, `a` retains its value (which happens to be the same as `c`)

Comment: According to this , Im wrong. `a` gets its value from `b` and not from `1`

Comment: I don't see how this is the case. In your function, you are assigning the value of `j` to be the value of `window.j` (not a *reference* to `window.j`), to which you are assigning a function as the value that alerts "3". Then you assign window.j2 to the value of `j`. Thus when you invoke `window.j2`, it invokes the value of `j`.

Answer (score 0):

You are right technically but are confused with reference / value assignment i think. Technically `a` does get it's **value** from `b` but there is no reference to `b` therefore if your were to do `b = null` it would have no affect to `a`, which is what you're seeing in your example.

`a` inherits the value of `b` without relying on `b` still existing or having that same value later on when you refer back to `a`. The assignment happens right to left so actually reads `a = ( b = 1)`

Answer (score 0):

The "=" operator associates to the right so "a=b=1" is equivalent to "a=(b=1)". So 1 is assigned to b first with a result of 1, which is then assigned to a.