# Why is this array being passed by reference and not by value, and how can I change this?

Tags: javascript, arrays, pass-by-reference

I was working on a bug in some code that I wrote, and the culprit turned out to be this snippet (simplified for the sake of the question):

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 5, 4];
// later...
function f(arr) {
    var sorted = arr.sort();
    // other stuff
}
// later...
console.log(a);
// logs [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]!
```

My question is, why does `a` stay sorted after the function is done? Surely in JS all variables are passed by value as opposed to reference?

Comment: i dont see any function call

Comment: I believe this answers your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835070/is-there-thing-like-pass-by-value-pass-by-reference-in-javascript#2835203

Answer (score 0):

Look at this for a full description

> [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: Sorry, but this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: You are right but I can't add comments.

Answer (score -1):

Array is an Object. In javascript all Objects are passed by reference.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is wrong. Javascript doesn't have "pass by reference" (like in C++ or PHP).

Comment: Objects are passed by reference only in javascript and I am sure about it.
I made a simple fiddle for it.
http://jsfiddle.net/murli2308/npag0fj4/

Comment: This topic has been discussed ad nauseum, please read the answers in the linked thread. In short, js passes everything by value, but this very value is always a reference (=pointer).