# What's the best way to keep an object property linked to a value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My question is related to a directive that I have refactored:

**HTML**

```
<!-- Before -->
<slider value="sliderValue" floor="0" ceil="maxPrice"></slider>

<!-- New version -->
<slider value="sliderValue" options="sliderOptions"></slider>

<!-- Both directives use '=' bindings... -->
```

**JS**

```
$scope.sliderValue=0;
$scope.maxPrice = 1000;

$scope.sliderOptions = {
    floor: 0,
    ceil: $scope.maxPrice
};

//later
$scope.maxPrice = 2000;
```

With the old version, I could update `$scope.maxPrice`, and it would automatically update the scope value of `ceil`in the directive. I would like to achieve the same with the new version.

The first idea to come to my mind is using a `$watch` on `$scope.maxPrice`, but I have read many people explaining that using `$watch` is a bad practice.

Then, I could update `$scope.sliderOptions.ceil` manually every time I update `$scope.maxPrice` but this is quite annoying.

**N.B.** `$scope.maxPrice` is a business-logic value used in several places of the application while `$scope.sliderOptions` is only used for the slider directive.

Comment: Ah, I see! I can post you an answer using a service. It might require reworking some of your code but I'm quite confident it would be best for the structure of your application. Interested?

Comment: I'm not sure of what you want to do but the directive can't access a service since it can be reused in any application.

Answer (score 0):

After giving it some thought and discussion I guess you're limited to wrapping `maxprice` in an simple object. The reason to do so would be because JavaScript can't pass numbers by reference. More information on the topic:
[Is there thing like pass by value pass by reference in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835070/is-there-thing-like-pass-by-value-pass-by-reference-in-javascript)

*Proposed solution*

```
$scope.sliderValue=0;
$scope.maxPrice = {value: 1000};

$scope.sliderOptions = {
    floor: 0,
    ceil: $scope.maxPrice
};

//later
$scope.maxPrice.value = 2000;
```

Comment: I understand that numbers can't be passed by reference. However, I don't like this solution because I have dozens of options that can be passed to the slider and I don't want to force the user to do `{floor: {value:0}, ceil: {value: $scope.maxPrice}, etc...}`. Also, since `$scope.maxPrice` belongs to business logic, I don't like the idea of modifying it because the slider needs it to have a mandatory structure.