# How to convert an array into a hierarchical array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have some data which is

```
var currentData = [
    {'ticket':'CAP', 'child':'CT-1'},
    {'ticket':'CAP', 'child':'CT-2'},
    {'ticket':'CT-1', 'child':'CT-1-A'},
    {'ticket':'CT-1', 'child':'CT-1-B'}
];
```

The data is flat and I need to convert it into something like:

```
{
    'ticket': 'CAP',
    children : [{
        'ticket' : 'CT-1',
        'children' : [{
            'ticket' : 'CT-1-A',
            'children' : []
        }, {
            'ticket' : 'CT-1-B',
            'children' : []
        }],
        [{
            'ticket' : 'CT-2',
            'children' : []
        }]
    }]
}
```

(I think the above is valid)?

I'm very lost as to how. I am going to show my effort but, I'm not sure if my approach is correct or not.

```js
var currentData = [{'ticket':'cap', 'child':'CT-1'},{'ticket':'cap', 'child':'CT-2'}, {'ticket':'CT-1', 'child':'CT-1-A'},{'ticket':'CT-1', 'child':'CT-1-B'}];

var newList = [];
function convert(list){
    if (newList.length <= 0){
        var child = [];
        var emptyChild = [];
        child.push({'ticket': list[0].child, 'child': emptyChild });
        newList.push({'ticket': list[0].ticket, 'children' : child});
        list.splice(0,1);
    } // the if statement above works fine
    
    for(var i = 0;  i < list.length; i++) {
        var ticket = list[i].ticket;
        for(var j = 0; j < newList.length; j++) {
            if (newList[j].ticket == ticket){
                var child;
                var emptyChild = [];
                child = {'ticket': list[i].child, 'child': emptyChild };
                newList[j].children.push(child);
                list.splice(i,1);
                break;
            } // the if above works
            else{
                var child2 = getFromChildren(ticket, newList, list[i]); // child2 is Always null, even if getFromChildren returns an object
                newList[j].children.push(child2);
                list.splice(i,1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }   
    
    if (list.length > 0){
        convert(list);
    }
}

function getFromChildren(ticket, list, itemToAdd){

    if (list == null || list[0].children == null)
        return;
    
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i] == null)
        return;
        
        if (list[i].ticket == ticket){
            list[i].child.push(itemToAdd.child); // ** can't do this, javascript passes by value, not by reference :(
        } else{
            getFromChildren(ticket, list[i].children, itemToAdd);
        }
    }
}

convert(currentData);
```

I think I've made a mess of it. In the comments I've put a ** explaining that it isn't working due to JavaScript not passing by reference, however upon [further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835070/is-there-thing-like-pass-by-value-pass-by-reference-in-javascript) I don't think that is correct as I'm passing the object which is by reference?

*Edit*

The data, shown with `currentData` will not always start at the root sadly either

Comment: Why one childless object has its `children` property set to `null` and the other set to an empty array `[]`.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir, a simple mistake on part, sorry. I've updated the question, but to be honest, it could be an empty array `[]` or `null`, either would be valid/acceptable

Comment: what you want to convert your data to is not syntactically correct, i assume you forgot to add a `]}` at the end ?

Comment: will it always start from root?

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee, no, sadly it won't. I've updated my question

Comment: @Taurus, you are correct. I believe it's now correct.

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions the third child of the `children` property is just a value, with no property to refer to it; to see what i mean, just run the `children` property's value in a browser, a `SyntaxError` will be thrown (i am referring to the array that holds `CT-2`).

Comment: The error is still there, is this what you want your data to look like: `var obj = {
'ticket': 'CAP',
children : [{
'ticket' : 'CT-1',
children : [{
'ticket' : 'CT-1-A',
'children' : []
}, {
'ticket' : 'CT-1-B',
'children' : []
}]
},
{  
'ticket' : 'CT-2',
children : []
}
]
};` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function convert(arr) {
  var children = {};                                         // this object will hold a reference to all children arrays

  var res = arr.reduce(function(res, o) {                    // for each object o in the array arr
    if(!res[o.ticket]) {                                     // if there is no object for the element o.ticket
      res[o.ticket] = {ticket: o.ticket, children: []};      // then creates an object for it
      children[o.ticket] = res[o.ticket].children;           // and store a reference to its children array
    }
    if(!res[o.child]) {                                      // if there is no object for the element o.child
      res[o.child] = {ticket: o.child, children: []};        // then creates an object for it
      children[o.child] = res[o.child].children;             // and store a reference to its children array
    }
    return res;
  }, {});
  
  arr.forEach(function(o) {                                  // now for each object o in the array arr
    children[o.ticket].push(res[o.child]);                   // add the object of o.child (from res) to its children array
    delete res[o.child];                                     // and remove the child object from the object res
  });
  
  return res;
}



var currentData = [
    {'ticket':'CAP', 'child':'CT-1'},
    {'ticket':'CAP', 'child':'CT-2'},
    {'ticket':'CT-1', 'child':'CT-1-A'},
    {'ticket':'CT-1', 'child':'CT-1-B'}
];

console.log(convert(currentData));
```

**Explanation:**

The `reduce` part creates an object of the form: `{ ticket: "...", children: [] }` for each element (child or not). So right after `reduce`, the object `res` will be:

```
res = {
    'CAP': { ticket: 'CAP', children: [] },
    'CT-1': { ticket: 'CT-1', children: [] },
    'CT-2': { ticket: 'CT-2', children: [] },
    'CT-1-A': { ticket: 'CT-1-A', children: [] },
    'CT-1-B': { ticket: 'CT-1-B', children: [] },
}
```

Now comes the `forEach` bit which loops over the array once more, and now for each object it fetches the object of `.child` from `res` above, push it into `.ticket` object's `children` (which a reference to it is stored in `children` object), then remove the `.child` object from the object `res`.

Comment: I need to learn/read up on the `reduce` function. This code is very different to my approach but I feel it will take me a little while to digest the difference. Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: You're welcome! I've added a brief explanation of my approach. And here is the link to [**MDN's docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) about `reduce`.

Answer (score 1):

Below uses reduce to get the data grouped to a Map, then I convert the data to an object like you've shown above. You'll need a modern browser to run below snippet, or use a transpiler like babeljs to convert it to es5 syntax.

```js
let currentData = [
    {'ticket':'CAP', 'child':'CT-1'},
    {'ticket':'CAP', 'child':'CT-2'},
    {'ticket':'CT-1', 'child':'CT-1-A'},
    {'ticket':'CT-1', 'child':'CT-1-B'}
];

let children = currentData.map(e => e.child);
currentData.sort((a,b) => children.indexOf(a.ticket));

let res = currentData.reduce((a,b) => {
    if (! children.includes(b.ticket)) {
        return a.set(b.ticket, (a.get(b.ticket) || [])
            .concat({ticket: b.child,
                children: currentData
                    .filter(el => el.ticket === b.child)
                    .map(el => ({ticket: el.child, children: []}))}))
    }
    return a;
}, new Map);

let r = {};

for (let [key,value] of res.entries()) {
    r.ticket = key;
    r.children = value;
}

console.log(r);
```

Comment: You might need to update your browser. Above uses some ES6 syntax and won't work with IE @MyDaftQuestions

Comment: I activated babel, can you try it again? @MyDaftQuestions

Answer (score 1):

Solution using recursion, starting node can be changed.

```js
var currentData = [{'ticket': 'cap','child': 'CT-1'}, {'ticket': 'cap','child': 'CT-2'}, {'ticket': 'CT-1','child': 'CT-1-A'}, {'ticket': 'CT-1','child': 'CT-1-B'}];

function convert(data, start){
  return {
    ticket: start,
    childs: data.filter(d => d.ticket == start)
                .reduce((curr, next) => curr.concat([next.child]), [])
                .map(c => convert(data, c))
  }
}

let result = convert(currentData, 'cap');

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top: 0; max-height: none!important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a simple `for` approach, like this:

```js
var currentData = [
    {'ticket':'CAP', 'child':'CT-1'},
    {'ticket':'CAP', 'child':'CT-2'},
    {'ticket':'CT-1', 'child':'CT-1-A'},
    {'ticket':'CT-1', 'child':'CT-1-B'}
];
var leafs = {};
var roots = {};
var tickets = {};
for(var i=0; i<currentData.length; i++){
    var ticket = currentData[i].ticket;
    var child = currentData[i].child;
    if(!tickets[ticket]){
        tickets[ticket] = {ticket:ticket,children:[]};
        if(!leafs[ticket]){
            roots[ticket] = true;
        }
    }
    if(!tickets[child]){
        tickets[child] = {ticket:child,children:[]};
    }
    delete roots[child];
    leafs[child] = true;
    tickets[ticket].children.push(tickets[child]);
}
for(var ticket in roots){
    console.log(tickets[ticket]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are not familiar with `reduce`, `map` , `forEach` with callbacks to iterate, then here is a approach I came with, where the code is flat, storing object references in another map object and **iterating exactly once** the source array.

The code is much cleaner, if something is understandable add comments I will explain;

```js
var currentData = [
    {'ticket':'CT-1', 'child':'CT-1-A'},
    {'ticket':'CT-1', 'child':'CT-1-B'},
    {'ticket':'CAP', 'child':'CT-1'},
    {'ticket':'CAP', 'child':'CT-2'}
];
function buildHierarchy(flatArr) {
    let root = {},
        nonRoot = {},
        tempMap = {};
    Object.setPrototypeOf(root, nonRoot);
    for (let idx = 0; idx < flatArr.length; idx++) {
        let currTicket = flatArr[idx];
        let tempTicket = tempMap[currTicket.ticket] || {ticket: currTicket.ticket, children: []};
        tempMap[currTicket.ticket] = tempTicket;
        if (currTicket.child) {
            let tempChild = tempMap[currTicket.child] || {ticket: currTicket.child, children: []};
            tempTicket.children.push(tempChild);
            tempMap[currTicket.child] = tempChild;
            delete root[tempChild.ticket];
            nonRoot[tempChild.ticket] = true;
        }
        root[tempTicket.ticket] = true;

    }
    return tempMap[Object.keys(root)[0]];
}

console.log(buildHierarchy(currentData));
```

I have changed the sequence of your source array in order to put the root object anywhere, and the code should work on that.